# What drawbacks are there in preferential voting?

Tags: voting, voting-systems, australia

I recently discovered that Australia uses the [preferential voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_system_of_Australia#Preferential_voting) system. It looks like a great system, so great that I do not see any immediate drawbacks.

What are they?

Comment: Are you aware of the Arrow Impossibility Theorem? Its not a direct answer to your question, but its an important part of the discussion.  https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2/why-cant-voting-be-fair-if-there-are-more-than-two-alternatives?rq=1 https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/34638/mechanics-of-a-second-brexit-referendum/34721#34721 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem

Comment: (For clarity, I'd also raise that I *completely* disagree with the top voted answer in that dup question. In practice the spoiler effect is statistical fluke, and the alternatives to ranked choice voting are arguably all worse, so it's very much like the choice between democracy as a government vs some other alternative.)

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: thanks, the dup is indeed what I was asking for, better phrased. Should someone like me ddi not know what a "spoiler" is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoiler_effect

Comment: Drawback is that the current ruling parties/elite of a country will be penalized, so they won't want to implement it.

Comment: Note that Australia has two different preferential voting systems.  The question this is marked as a duplicate of only addresses the single-winner variant IRV.  Australia also uses the multi-winner variant STV in their Senate.