# Is single transferable vote an adaptation of instant runoff voting for multiple winners?

Tags: voting-systems

Is [Single Transferable Vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transferable_vote) system an exact adaptation of the [Instant Runoff Voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant-runoff_voting) system designed to select multiple winners?

Comment: Where are your links supposed to go? Also, what do you mean by "an exact adaptation"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Single Transferable Vote work?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-does-single-transferable-vote-work)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't your link already answer the question?

> Instant-runoff voting was devised in 1871 by American architect William Robert Ware, although it is, in effect, a special case of the single transferable vote system, which emerged independently in the 1850s.

**Edit:**

I've actually researched this more carefully, and [Ware's 1871 paper](https://books.google.com/books?id=W7QRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA192) is literally an implementation of Hare's STV, which credits Hare, by name, in the title.

So you have it backwards, and IRV is explicitly an adaptation of STV to single-winner elections.