# How did the electoral system work in late Ottoman empire and early Turkey?

Tags: election, parliament, history, turkey

I am reading about elections in the late Ottoman empire and early Turkey (1880-1935) and there always seemed to be these "secondary electors" elected by the people. These "secondary electors" then elect the members of the National Assembly.

Does anyone know how this system works and how these secondary electors were elected?

In [Wikipedia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-first-past-the-post-electoral-systems) it says that voters elect one secondary elector for the first 750 voters in a constituency, then one for every additional 500 voters.

But what does the "first 750 voters" mean? Does it mean the first 750 voters who came to vote in the constituency?

Also why did Turkey use these secondary electors to elect the members of national assembly instead of just letting people elect them directly?

Comment: There are two questions here.  I have an answer for one but not the other.  What should I do?

Comment: @phoog, Any answer would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry.  That was a passive-aggressive way of suggesting that you should ask the questions separately.

Comment: I think it is better suited for History.SE